# React Import looks in the wrong directory

Tags: reactjs

For some reason when I try to import one particular module, react refuses to look in the correct directory (./node_modules/). Instead it looks in the ./src/ directory and throws this error:

```
/src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-d3gantt' in '/Users/RAVEN/Desktop/frontend/materialui/material/src'
```

All of my other modules are imported correctly. What is it about this one in particular?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DefaultButton, CompoundButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { Image } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Image';
import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';
import { GanttChart } from "react-d3gantt";
import OilSite from './components/oilsite';
import BigButton from './components/bigButton';
import LeftNav from './components/leftNav';

import './index.css';
```

Edit: I used Create-React-App, in case this is relevant to my set up.

Comment: Just to confirm, (I've been caught out by this a few times before), that module has been installed properly and exists in node_modules?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. I checked that folder, and I do see it there. And the installer gave me no errors either.

Comment: Ok it actually looks like that module isn't setup properly. You could try `import GanttChart from 'react-d3gantt/src/index';` which is where their export lives.

Comment: I'm getting a new error now. Here is what I see:
`./node_modules/react-d3gantt/src/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (138:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     let domTree = this.buildDomTree();
|     return (
|       <svg
|         width={width + margins.left + margins.right}
|         height={height + margins.top + margins.bottom}`

Comment: This is webpack issue. Can we see your webpack config?

Comment: It's complaining about the svg element they are using in the library. Your Webpack config doesn't appear to use a loader for that type of element. As it is such a new module, it may be worth raising a GItHub issue with them, as there are no mentions of additional webpack requirements as part of their readme.

Comment: From my React app I'm able to import svg files and display them. Does this change the situation at all?

Comment: Loading SVG files is a little different. This is parsing an inline SVG which will end up in your bundled code. I would definitely sell help from the author of the module